Incrementing to the last decimal in python
I want to write function in python when given float or string for example 0.003214 to return me 0.003215, but if I give it 0.00321 to return 0.003211, it will apply on other floats also like 0.0000324 -> 0.00003241. What is wrong with my solution and how do I fix it?
def add_one_at_last_digit(v):
    after_comma = Decimal(v).as_tuple()[-1]*-1
    add = Decimal(1) / Decimal(10**after_comma)
    return Decimal(v) + add


Your function is bound not to work if you pass floating point numbers in. See this question. All of the example values you give will work if passed as strings into the function.

How do you know whether 0.003214 goes to 0.003215, or 0.0032141?  How do you know whether 0.0000324 goes to 0.0000325, or 0.00003241?

Here is a working solution
from decimal import Decimal

def add_one_at_last_digit(v: float | str) -> float:
    d = Decimal(str(v))
    
    decimal_places = abs(d.as_tuple().exponent)
    
    add = Decimal(f"1e-{decimal_places}")
    
    result = (d + add).quantize(Decimal(f"1e-{decimal_places}"))
    
    return float(result)

The key ideas are:

d = Decimal(str(v)) gives the a Decimal object with the exact number of decimal places. The string conversion does the trick here. For example

>>> Decimal(213.4)
Decimal('213.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625')
>>> Decimal("213.4")
Decimal('213.4')

You did not do this in your solution which is why your after_comma is wrong.

abs(d.as_tuple().exponent) gives the exact number of decimal places.
(d + add).quantize(Decimal(f"1e-{decimal_places}")) again quantizes it to remove imprecision.


I just tested it and it works fine. Values ​​ending with a 0 might behave differently than expected.
`print(add_one_at_last_digit(0.123)) # 0.124`   
`print(add_one_at_last_digit(0.129)) # 0.13`   
`print(add_one_at_last_digit(0.120)) # 0.13`   
`print(add_one_at_last_digit(0.199)) # 0.2`


Thanks for observing this. If 0.120 and 0.12 have to be treated differently, then the input must be a string and not a float. print(add_one_at_last_digit("0.120")) # 0.121. I have edited my answer to indicate the expected types.
